# Please download Drush error when trying to execute CiviHR install script

Tags: drush, civihr

I'm attempting to install CiviHR as per these instructions:

https://github.com/compucorp/civihr-installer

I'm using a GoDaddy shared linux server to install this on - but I have an issue. I've installed Drush on the server which seems to work - but the instructions ask for Drush to be globally available.

As far as I can see this means that the drush launcher needs to be able to work, however because this is a shared linux server - I don't seem to have the necessary permissions to make drush available globally.

So currently the civihr-install script falls over when checking for drush. Is there any nifty way of getting around this so the installer can use it?